# Request header difference for same URL on different server

Tags: http, https, xmlhttprequest, signalr.client

I am new to web applications and recently we migrated our application server(s) from Windows Server 2012 to windows Server 2019.

I am facing issue at signal R request URL with error Error during negotiation request  and I observed in the network tab of developer tools and observed

**windows server 2019:**

```
:scheme: https
accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-AU,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

**windows Server 2012**

```
  Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-AU,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    sec-fetch-site: same-site
    Cookie: Bearer= Some long token
    sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

I skipped origin and some other headers for security reasons.

I am calling a GET Method using this URL :path: /signalr/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&_=1681114992211

website is working and getting status code 200 on Windows server 2012 app server and IIS server.
Website is getting status code 401 on Windows server 2019 app server and IIS Server.

Anyone let me know why cross-site and same-site difference for the same call. I understood the request is different one is HTTP 1.1 and other header is HTTP 2.0

How to know why the difference and how to investigate it further?